# How to improve accuracy of random forest multiclass classification model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am working on a multi class classification for segmenting customers into 3 different classes based on their purchasing behavior and demographics. I cannot disclose the data set completely but in general it contains around 300 features and  50000 rows. I have tried the following methods but I am unable to achieve accuracy above 50% :

1. Tuning the hyperparameters ( I am using tuned hyperparameters after doing GridSearchCV)
2. Normalizing the dataset and then running my models
3. Tried different classification methods : OneVsRestClassifier, RandomForestClassification, SVM, KNN and LDA
4. I have also removed irrelevant features and tried running my models
5. My classes were imbalanced, so I have also tried using class_weight = balanced, oversampling using SMOTE, downsampling and resampling.

Is there something else I can try to improve my accuracy ( and by accuracy I mean f-score, precision and recall ).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Different data pre-processing is necessary for different machine learning algorithms. Random Forests are pretty simple in a way that they do not need scaling or normalization of the features.
Have you played with `n_estimators`, `max_features` and `min_samples_leaf`?

Comment: Yes I did while tuning the hyperparameters. I also did a GridSearchCV to determine the optimal parameters.

Comment: I have to admit that I prefer doing grid search the hard way (ugly for-loops) and save the scores I obtain. This way I can easily check if I am truly converging to a global minimum or if I need to extend the boundaries of my search. 
Another idea you should consider is performing a PCA on your data. Random Forests don't like correlation between the features, because individual trees are not independent on another

Comment: I have also tried the ugly for loops. Manually checking each hyperparameter. I will try doing PCA and check if something changes.

Comment: hope solution helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to tune below parameters

### n_estimators

This is the number of trees you want to build before taking the maximum voting or averages of predictions. Higher number of trees give you better performance but makes your code slower. You should choose as high value as your processor can handle because    this makes your predictions stronger and more stable. As your data size is bigger so it will take more time for each iteration but try this.

### max_features

These are the maximum number of features Random Forest is allowed to try in individual tree. There are multiple options available in Python to assign maximum features. Few of them are  :

- Auto/None : This will simply take all the features which make sense
  in every tree.Here we simply do not put any restrictions on the
  individual tree.

  sqrt : This option will take square root of the total number of
  features in individual run. For instance, if the    total number of
  variables are 100, we can only take 10 of them in    individual
  tree.”log2″ is another similar type of option for max_features.

  0.2 : This option allows the random forest to take 20% of variables in individual run. We can assign and value in a format “0.x” where we
  want x% of features to be considered.

### min_sample_leaf

Leaf is the end node of a decision tree. A smaller leaf makes the model more prone to capturing noise in train data. You can start with some minimum value like 75 and gradually increase it. See which value your accuracy is coming high.

Answer (score 1):

How is your training acc? I assume that your acc is your validation. If your training acc is way to high, som normal overfitting might be the case. Random forest normally handles overfitting very well.

What you could try is PCA of your data, and then try classify on that. This gives you the features which accounts for most variation in the data, thus can be a good idea to try, if you cannot classify on the original data (and also it reduces your features).

A side note: remember, that the fitting of SVM is quadratic in the number of points, thus reducing your data to around 10-20000 for tuning parameters and then fit a SVM on the full dataset with the optimal parameter for the subset, might also speed up the process.
Also remember to consider trying different kernels for the SVM.

Comment: My model is not overfitting. My training accuracy is around 60-70% in all the cases

Comment: But you should definitively use a PCA. 300 features can be way too many for RF if features are correlated with each other.

Comment: I agree with trying PCA and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a feature selection first using PCA or Random forest and then fit a chained classifier where first do a oneversesall and then a random forest or a decision tree. You should get a slightly better accuracy.